# Consistency in use of Gendersternchen

Tags: usage, gender

Articles in *Die Zeit*'s online magazine for young people, *Ze.tt*, use the *Gendersternchen*. For example, [today's article](https://ze.tt/wie-wir-durch-humor-lernen-koennen-entspannter-durchs-leben-zu-gehen/?utm_campaign=ref&utm_content=zett_zon_teaser_teaser_x&utm_medium=fix&utm_source=zon_zettaudev_int&wt_zmc=fix.int.zettaudev.zon.ref.zett.zon_teaser.teaser.x) about the power of humor contains sentences such as:

- Als Clownin verkleidet geht sie in Senior*innenheime, Krankenhäuser und auf Hospizstationen.
- Auch die Bewegung der Klinikclown*innen stamme ursprünglich aus den
  USA.

The last sentence of the article is:

- Den (Rock) hat ihr eine der Bewohner*innen im Altenheim geschenkt.

I would have thought it should be either:

- Den hat ihr eine der Bewohnerinnen im Altenheim geschenkt

or (for sake of consistency):

- Den hat ihr eine*r der Bewohner*innen im Altenheim geschenkt.

My question is therefore: Is there a reason why *eine* is not '*gendergesternchent*' (for example, because it follows the rules in some style guide)?

Comment: It's a practical joke. It's very German to be very serious about such a laughable matter.

Comment: @Janka Actually this is really not more than a joke but unfortunately some people are very serious about this Gendersternchen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole topic of language gendering in German beyond the traditional "when in doubt, make it male" ( :D ) is largely a work in progress. So I wouldn't expect fully formed, estabished rules yet. But [according to Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendersternchen) the Gendersternchen is used in nouns, so it wouldn't be used in "eine".

Also, the Gendersternchen is meant to show that the members of *a group* of people don't necessary all have the same gender. So, if we look at

> Den Rock hat ihr eine der Bewohner*innen im Altenheim geschenkt.

"eine" refers to one of the residents, not the whole group. This specific resident is seemingly female (which pronouns and articles an individual prefers for themselves is a whole other can of worms that's well beyond the scope of this answer, and my expertise). On the other hand, "Bewohner*innen" refers to all the residents. Here the Gendersternchen denotes that among that group, there are possibly males, females and whatever other gender the individual identifies as.

Comment: In your example "eine der Bewohnerinnen" (= one of the female residents) would be completely fine without this Sternchen-nonsense. Why should a both-genders form be used if the phrase deals with a woman?

Comment: Thanks. I had encountered _jede*r_ before - why is why I asked about _eine*r_. But I see now that _eine_ here '_refers to one of the residents, not the whole group_' - and so _eine*r_ would not be appropriate unless the writer wanted to conceal the gender. Nevertheless, @puck's comment is pertinent. And why not simply: _eine Bewohnerin_?

Comment: @Shoe "Die Bewohnerinnen" and "die Bewohner*innen" refer to different groups of people. Without the Gendersternchen, "die Bewohnerinnen" refers to all residents who identify as female. With the Gendersternchen, "die Bewohner*innen" refers to all residents, regardless of gender. Whether you say, one of the first group or one of the second, is your discretion as the speaker. In your example, the author chose to refer to all residents with "Bewohner*innen".

Comment: @Shoe Also, I wouldn't say that "eine*r" necessary _conceals_ the gender. It basically leaves the question open - the person it refers to might be female, they might be male, they might be something in between, they might be something completely different we don't even have a pronoun or article for yet.

Comment: Thanks. You have clarified the issue for me. It would be nice if German could be rebooted such that _Bewohner, Clown, Lehrer_ usw. can be understood as refering to any gender. After all it works in English, and if the gender is important (and not clear from the context, e.g. by the presence of a pronoun) then _male, female, intersexual_, etc. can be prepended. I don't watch German TV any more, but does every ad for medical products still come with the recommendation: _Fragen Sie Ihren Arzt oder Apotheker_? How would you actually say: _Fragen Sie Ihre*n Arzt*in oder Apotheker*in_?

Comment: @Shoe The prase is still around to my knowledge. But this area is highly regulated legally. For example, companies often quarrel with the authorities whether a product is "Medizin" (a medicine) or "Medizinprodukt" (a medical product). That distinction has implications for where the product can be sold, whether you need a prescription, whether insurance companies have to pay for it and so on. Therefore, I wouldn't be suprised if the phrase in question in this exact wording were legally required, or if the companys' legal departments were really vary about changing it.

Comment: There's a discussion of the issue in the second comment on the first comments page on today's ZON article about FFF. It contains a term that applies very nicely to my view of recent developments: _Sprachnostalgiker_! https://www.zeit.de/gesellschaft/zeitgeschehen/2019-05/fridays-for-future-klimaschutz-aktivismus-schulstreik-demonstrationen-fs#comments